# moving project dependency library to common folder in tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, architecture

I have a web application(maven) i have 4 different modules.The jars used in one  module is 10+ so i have 4 now so almost 40 libraries and some commonly used libraries are shared among them gets replicated (added to class path multiple times).

Is there a possible way that i can make a separate folder inside tomcat directory and load the jars from there? if so can someone guide me with the steps?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider putting them in the Tomcat/lib folder and define the scope as provided in the pom.xml if you are using Maven, that would prevent them from being packaged with your modules.

Comment: so all the 40+ jars(removing duplicates) will be held inside tomcat/lib and how to define scope and the reference in the pom.xml? can you give some steps to achieve this

Comment: Take a look at this link- https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html.

Comment: Just to be clear, Tomcat/lib will be in classpath automatically, so the scope has nothing to do at runtime. It only tells the packaging system not to bundle them with your war/jar. So as long as those jars are there in your Tomcat/lib folder, they would be referenced in your project.